# Item appearing when reaching a certain height (scroll effect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I just found this code :

script type="text/javascript">

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(window).scroll(function () {
          var height = $('body').height();
          var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
          var opacity = 1;


          if(scrollTop > 400) {
              opacity = 0;
          }

       $('.social').css('opacity', opacity);
    });
});
```

Although, i'd like to reverse these effects. I'd like the element to start opactiy : 0 and fadein when reaching a certain height (in this case 400).

Thanks

Comment: Do you know JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure if you really tried it yourself, I'd say:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(window).scroll(function () {
          var height = $('body').height();
          var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
          var opacity = 0;


          if(scrollTop > 400) {
              opacity = 1;
          }

       $('.social').css('opacity', opacity);
    });
});
```

(not tested, but I'm pretty confident that's what you were looking for.)

Comment: I've tried it this way, but i changed a little bit the code to:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function(){
var opacity = 1- ( $(window).scrollTop() / $('#fading').height());
if (opacity<0) opacity=0;
if (opacity>1) opacity=1;
   
//$('#debug').html('ScrollTop:' + $(window).scrollTop() + '<br>Opacity: ' + opacity);
$('#fading').stop().fadeTo(250, opacity);    
});
</script>

seems smoother but again, I have to switch the opacity functions

Comment: glad it worked out for you. just a hint: ALWAYS wrap statements in curly braces, that helps kepping the code readable